# Cross-browser dropcaps using :first-letter pseudo element

Tags: css

Having searched high and low online, I'm really struggling to find a robust cross-browser dropcap solution using CSS. The below code works well in most modern browsers, but positions slightly oddly in MS Edge and IE. These browsers are important for our client and therefroe I'd like to try and resolve this solution in pure CSS.

I have also tried a jquery approach that wraps the first character in a span, but the CSS remains the same and has the same issues.

```
// Drop cap
p {
    white-space: pre-wrap;

    &:first-of-type {
        &:first-letter {
            float: left;
            font-size: 130px;
            line-height: 65px;
            padding-top: 30px;
            padding-right: 10px;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but "slightly oddly" is not a very good problem description. Can you produce a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue? I made [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/4mgw05dm/1/), but I don't see many problems.